# Why struct which have list<struct type>::iterator can't delete by clear()?

Tags: c++

I'm an iOS developer, and I'm unfamiliar with C++.So, I can't understand why imageMap's content can't be deleted by clear() method?

```
struct ImageNode
{
  string key;
  UIImage *image;(UIImage is a class in Objective-C)
};

struct ImagePointer
{
  list<ImageNode *>::iterator it;
  bool isLRUQueue;
};

list<ImageNode *> FIFOQueue;
list<ImageNode *> LRUQueue;
map<string, ImagePointer *> imageMap;

//clear method
- (void)clear
{
  //why need for loop???
  for (auto it = imageMap.begin(); it != imageMap.end(); it++)
  {
    delete *it->second->it;
    delete it->second;
  }
  FIFOQueue.clear();
  LRUQueue.clear();
  imageMap.clear();
}
```

Comment: The clear() method doesn't call delete by itself. If it is allocated by new, then delete needs to be called unless it is unique_ptr. unique_ptr disposes by itself.

Comment: Since `std::list` is using a template, how would it know if the type needs to be deleted as a pointer or if it is just a plain non-pointer type?

Comment: A similar  delete loop is needed for FIFOQueue and LRUQueue containers if the memory is allocated by new method. Else resource leak will be there.

Comment: 1. This is not C++, maybe a mix of Objective-C and C++. 2. What is the error message and at what line is it?

Comment: @SatishChalasani I think your answer is what I need to know.Thank you.

Comment: @OlafDietsche 1.yes,you're right. 2.There is no error. I just can't understand the difference between clear and delete.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand why imageMap's content can't be deleted by clear()

Consider that even if you do store pointers in a list, does not mean that you want to delete those pointers when you remove them from the list:

```
std::list<int*> l;
int i;
l.push_back(&i);
l.clear; // if list deleted the pointer contained within the list
         // then bad things would happen
```

`std::list` cannot read your mind and cannot know whether you want to delete the pointers. *You* must delete the pointers when they need to be deleted. Clear does nothing more than remove elements from the list.